# Is it possible in Django to iterate the creation of a model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create a model with 100 columns. Is it possible to iterate in my models.py file to create many entries at once?

This is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
class AgeFactor(models.Model):
    '''
    Used to populate a table with all the age-factor numbers
    '''
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    event_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    oc = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=4)
    for lp in range(101):
       if lp > 4:
           (f"{lp} = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=4)")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, although this is not how to do that. What you can do is use a loop mechanism with:

```
class AgeFactor(models.Model):
    '''
    Used to populate a table with all the age-factor numbers
    '''
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    event_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    oc = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=4)
    for lp in range(5, 101):
       locals()[f'data{lp}'] = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=4)
```

This will make a set of fields named `data5`, `data6`, `data7`, … `data100`.

That being said, it is rather "ugly", and often you can better define a many-to-one relation with a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) since that makes the data more "flat".

Furthermore if I run this locally it takes some time for Django to fully evaluate the model, so I do not know how well Django scales with a large amount of fields (the `for` loop itself is not the problem, but Django has a lot of bookkeeping for these fields).

Finally querying can also be *slow*, because the database has to load all these columns, furthermore queries will be quite large, because the `SELECT` part will enumerate all the `data…` fields.

Comment: Thank you very much Willem for your feedback.
This worked.  I am simply trying to create a lookup table where the "data-{lp}" is a persons age (from 5-100).  I'm probably not going about this in the proper way.  Just learning.
Thank you.

Comment: @Dylan: you can perhaps make use of a JSON field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/ (although for non-PostgreSQL, the queries on a JSON field are very limited).